Manager/managee - role word question
What is the story behind the phenomenon where you can indicate a relationship between two people by adding -ee on the end of a word.
Eg: mentor/mentee. Employer/employee.
It seems to indicate a power dynamic, giver/receiver of action.
But it seems can't you always use this.  Some just don't work
Eg: Manager/managee

Not sure, but mentee works more as a useful non-word like unbold. Emphasized like "if there were such a word." I'd use managee with the same tone as donor/donee, and not in serious writing.

strictly speaking, suffix -ee is a borrowing from French (OED). As a past participle, I expect. Which in principle should only work with French / Romance words anyway. But it's probably still a "productive" morphological shift - I can't think of a recent neologism based on it, but I bet they exist.

There is no entry in either Cambridge Dictionary or Merriam-Webster for 'managee'. I think AmE speakers love to invent new words such as standee – someone who is standing, only in M-W. Other usage is for the object of an action, such as employee.

@YosefBaskin: The full OED has mentee as formed within English, by derivation from 1942. Mentor as a noun from 1750, but I was surprised to see mentor verb wasn't recorded until 1918. So the "English derived" term popped up pretty soon after it was even possible for it to exist. You couldn't derive the "giver / receiver" format until it was a verb, I think.

There is a sittee on my settee.

Yes, and more recently protectee (US Secret Service).

@WeatherVane I would have thought that was sitter and the sittee would be the person who sat the sitter there (or perhaps the settee itself).  Some of these can be confusing, such as using rentee to mean landlord.

Well, manager does not have one. Not every word can just have ee added on. Though many legal words can: donor-donee, lessor-lessee etc.

Note that "mentor" came into English as a noun to describe people who acted like Mentor, the adviser of Odysseus. "Mentee" from half a Greek word with a French suffix - only in English!

English is a mongrel language
The -ee is an Anglo-French import from “-é” for past participles used as nouns. It entered the vernacular through its use in legal documents where it came to be used in pairs with -er/-or suffixes.
The -er suffix is from Old English creating an agent/actor noun. It is most commonly used of words that have Germanic roots, but there are many exceptions.
But, in legal documents and words derived from Latin, the Latin “-or” suffix was usually used. This has led to some triples like “advisor/adviser/advisee” where there is an ‘official’ role, an ‘unofficial’ role, and a target.
This convoluted origin is the reason why it works with some words and not others - there’s no system here, just historical accident.

Many are opposed to the idea that "if it's not in the OED, it doesn't exist." Because, you see, words are being added to the OED every day.
The "ee" suffix can be added to pretty much any word you like. It might sound jocose in some (most) cases, but that in itself might be a good thing.
Driver: drive-ee.
Ruler: rule-ee.
Writer: write-ee or writeree.
Voter: voteree.
Listener: listeneree.
Why not?
The term "non-word," while quite useful sometimes, must nonetheless be used sparingly and meaningfully. Applying it gratuitously is bad form.

A listener listens. So, liteneree makes no sense at all.

I can understand driver / drivee (but we have driven already) and ruler / rule (ditto ruled). But writee? Would that be a trainee writer? Someone who's written / tattooed on? Written about? I don't see any use for that derived term, and I don't believe you'd be able to cite any credible examples.

writeree, voteree and listeneree? Oh my goodness. They are for inarticulate people who need to invent a word when they don't know 'reader' and 'candidate', or IDK what a listeneree is supposed to be. Please don't promote this.

Three downvotes; I won't add one. ELU deals with standard usages, not suggestions that have no or negligible currency. As stated before on ELU, productivity is gradable and can't be used to license just anything produced by patterning. 'Teachee' has little currency. 'snipee' less, and no creditable supporting references as far as I can see.  Yes, OED claims not to list every acceptable English word (and Wiktionary lists far more), but protologisms are off-topic on ELU.

@Lambie: A listeneree is the one the listener listens TO.

That is commonly known as the speaker. It makes no sense to invent a word that is more complicated than one that exists.
